# Meteor with multiple Mongo DBs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, database

I've just started with Meteor and MongoDB. I was wondering if there is a way to use two or more DBs at once.
These DBs have to be generated on runtime.

The idea is that I have a few user groups which are absolutely not allowed to access data of the other user group. If there is another way tell me.

Comment: Why would they be able to access data from other user groups, if you only have one database?

Comment: They need the same tables and it is not allowed to cache the data at the client (I ground them for offline-mode). You know what I mean?

Comment: I don't really get your problem. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: The data in my DB are encrypted. For the case the app is running offline, I move the DB in an AppCache (https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/appcache). But the client has decrypted data. And then there are decrypted data which are not allowed to access. The thing is: I try to get only data which I am allowed to access.

Comment: You can [`publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) specific data to specific clients based on credentials.  It won't matter whether it's in the same database, or collection, or document.  If you don't publish it - the client won't get it.  Can you expand on why that wouldn't work in your case?

Comment: Well the idea was to ahve 1 DB per customer. Every DB has of course many tables (about 10). If a customer's DB gets broken (due to invalid data or something) it would be way more easier to move to last backup without changing data of the other customers. Currently I'm trying to use different `MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have done it...long ago but I still want to post the answer here.

What you need is something like this:

```
dbCustomer = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(
    CUSTOMER_DB_URL + customerId
);
```

This way you create your custom driver which you use while creating a new collection:

```
Products['procucts' + customerId] = new Meteor.Collection(
    'products' + customerId,
    {
        _driver: dbCustomer,
        idGeneration: 'STRING'
    }
);
```

So why have I done this `Products['productus' + customerId]` instead if simply `Products` ?

Here you have to be aware of the MinoMongo db on the client. The client doesn't care about which driver you are using (use the driver only on server side). Imagine the case a user logs out and logs in to another customer. Now he is working with a different database BUT only on the server. On the client you still have only 1 database with 1 collection named `Products`. What know? Exactly! You have both data the ones from the old customer and the ones from the new customer.

That's not a problem of data security but you will see both data too (which is clearly false). To prevent this you need 2 separate collections on the client. To achieve this you add the `customerId` to the collection.

That's it.